# How do I save all images from .xls file?

Tags: xls, libreoffice

I've got a `xls` file with exactly 167 images that I must save and post on a website. The sheer number itself is painful, but what complicates things is that you can't directly save images from Calc - you need to copy it to Writer first and then save.

This isn't the way I would like to do things, so is there a way to save all the graphics in the file somehow?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Open the xls file in OpenOffice or LibreOffice
2. save it as a open document (`.ods`).
3. rename file to  have `.zip` extension
4. uncompress that zip file

All images should be in a `Pictures/` directory in that zip file.

This also works if you are given a .PPT which can be saved in Impress.

Comment: That - is - **AWESOME**!

Comment: @Oxwivi: You welcome. This shows beauty of open standards. Isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, stuff like these small workarounds makes me love open softwares and standards even more!

Comment: nice tip! same works for open document presentation (.odp).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get scripty there are some perl scripts to unpack Open Document Formats at:

http://books.evc-cit.info/odbook/ch01.html#unpack-program-example